# Expanding Rally Custom grid rows to show task automatically

Tags: rally, tampermonkey

I am using custom grid to show my stories on dashboard widgets. I want to see my task under story too. This cannot be done unless, I manually click on small triangular image and the expand row to show tasks under story. Is there a way to do this automatically through setting or script like tampermonkey?

Comment: The person downvoting this question care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using tampermonkey!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Expand Rally Tasks
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       Main Shayar Badnam
// @match        https://rally1.rallydev.com/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            $('.x4-tree-elbow-img.x4-tree-elbow-plus.x4-tree-expander').click();$('.x4-tree-elbow-img.x4-tree-elbow-end-plus.x4-tree-expander').click();
        }
        ,2000
    );
    $().ready();
})();
```

Comment: who is down voting? Please explain, just downvote doesn't help.